# Node.js + Postgres highest matching to lowest matchig datas

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In my node application i am executing a select query.Suppose consider user is giving input as "abcdef" .i will take first 4 letters from that string say "abcd",and i will check for entries matching "abcd" using `ILIKE` command.

My query is:

```
client.query("select * from tn_village where level3 ILIKE '%"+substring+"%' OR level4 ILIKE '%"+substring+"%' OR level5 ILIKE '%"+substring+"%' OR level6 ILIKE '%"+substring+"%' OR level7 ILIKE '%"+substring+"%' OR level8 ILIKE '%"+substring+"%' OR level9 ILIKE '%"+substring+"%'" ,function(err,result)
{

res.send(result);
});
```

Here substring is "abcd"..I am getting result in alphabetical order.`. But what i want is i have to show the row which is exactly matching first say row for "abcde" first and then the  remaining results,,`

Help me to solve this..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can You please say why its downvoted??

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. The query doesn't include an order by clause, so maybe it wasn't entirely clear what you've already tried (despite mentioning that you have an alphabetic sorting in the text) and it looks like there might be some extraneous information (like mentioning that you're taking a substring). Either way, hopefully my answer helped.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you're sanitizing your inputs - if you're just embedding your substrings in your query like that without taking any precautions (like using placeholders instead of string concatenation) you're exposing yourself to sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

You could do two levels of ordering where the first level is used to discriminate between exact and partial matches and the second level for alphabetical ordering. For instance,

```
order by case when test_column = input_string then 0
              else 1 end,
         input_string
```

The first level of that ordering will be 0 for exact matches and 1 otherwise. That way if a row matches exactly then the case statement evaluates to 0, which will put that row ahead of inexact matches, for which the case statement evaluates to 1. Then, for all rows with an inexact match the first sorting level will be the same (1), but the second level may differ and will simply give the alphabetic sorting of those rows.